# How to associate role to a channel in a single command ? How to get role id?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a command creating a channel and a role according to the argument passed by the user. I struggle to overwrite the permissions in a way that only the created role has access to the created channel.

How do I get role id from role name ? This could solve the problem. I tried with utils.get but I don't know how to really use this function...

Here's my code :

```py
@bot.command() 
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def salon_create(ctx, arg):   
    guild = ctx.guild
    role = await guild.create_role(name=arg)
    print(role)
    cat=ctx.channel.category 
    role=discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=arg)
    print(role)
    roles = {
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    #guild.get_role(role): discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
}
    await guild.create_text_channel(name=arg, overwrites=roles, category=cat)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`create_role` returns the `Role` object it creates, you can just use it directly:

```
@bot.command() 
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def salon_create(ctx, arg):   
    guild = ctx.guild
    role = await guild.create_role(name=arg)
    cat=ctx.channel.category 
    roles = {
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    }
    await guild.create_text_channel(name=arg, overwrites=roles, category=cat)
```